# PayPal Checkout Installment Plans (for Brazil or Mexico)

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment

I am trying to implement a payment solution on my site via paypal, however when I click on the credit card option, there is no installment option, I would like to know if there is any way to enable parcel payment?

[Paypal Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcU6C.png)

[Paypal Checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBHh7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installment plans / parcelas / mensualidades are available specifically for Brazilian PayPal accounts selling in BRL, or Mexican PayPal accounts selling in MXN (so a $1,00 USD transaction per your screenshot will not work)

You can enable them on the seller account by going to: https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/installmentplan

Note that the amount of the transaction must be greater or equal to the minimum amount you configure there (so a $1,00 USD transaction per your screenshot is unlikely to qualify)

During checkout, the buyer may not see installment options until they enter the first 6-8 digits of a local card issued by a bank or other financial institution that supports installments.